# Join/see UV's of different objects

Tags: modeling, uv

I have to export an object to a game engine, and Id like to keep the different parts of it as seperate objects but while unwrapping I have a hard time knowing if they overlap. Is there anyway to see all the UV's or join them?

Answer (score 3):

### Just previewing other UVs

There is an option in the UV Editor which - under certain circumstances - allows to see the UVs of other objects. Those circumstances are:

- both objects use the same material, the material is active, and the texture is assigned
- before entering `Edit Mode`, both objects have been selected
- the `Draw other Objects` option is checked in the Image Editor (see screenshot below)

[image: See both UVs at same time]

### Editing other UVs at the same time

Use the `Texture Atlas` Add-on shipped with Blender to do this. After enabling it in the Add-on manager, you'll find a panel in the Properties Editor of the Render Settings tab. Select all objects which should receive the same UV space first, and then hit the <kbd>+</kbd> key to add a new Atlas. Then, hit the <kbd>Start Manual Unwrap</kbd> button.

[image: manual unwrap]

All objects will be joined, you can edit the UVs as if they were one. In fact, at the moment they actually **are** one object, so pay attention beforehand to your modifiers. When you're done, hit the <kbd>Finish Manual Unwrap</kbd> button to separate the objects back to their original state.